# Behavior of font style for given font family windows 10 vs Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, fonts

```
FontFamily family = new FontFamily("Aharoni");
bool supported = family.IsStyleAvailable(FontStyle.Italic);
```

I have installed Aharoni font in both windows 10 and windows 7 machines.
After that tested above code and I found following observations.

```
supported = true //windows 10
supported = false //windows 7
```

So in our application font object `Font font = new Font("Aharoni", 10f);` Its shows 'Font Aharoni does not support style Regular' exception message. in windows 7 but works in windows 10.
We are investigating that why font object works in above case for windows 10.
Is there any changes from Microsoft? If anybody know please share your views.

Thanks!

Comment: What exception is thrown? Please post the verbatim text of the exception.

Comment: Its shows 'Font Aharoni does not support style Regular' exception message.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and put all relevant information _there_